# Error installing node module

Tags: node.js

I've just install the recent node-gyp and I'm using node v4.4.7.

When trying to install node module i'm getting this weird error:

```
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/node_modules/libxml-xsd/node_modules/libxmljs-mt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/xmljs/src/libxmljs.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/xmljs/src/libxmljs.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/node_modules/libxmljs-mt/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /node_modules/libxml-xsd/node_modules/libxmljs-mt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please note that in the error it's written i'm using node 0.10.25.
When I type:

```
node -v
```

I get:

```
v4.4.7
```

Can someone help?

Comment: It's common problem. You must configure node-gyp - https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp or try node-pre-gyp.

Answer (score 3):

First try to install *build-essential* by running the following.

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

If it says that it is already installed, then first remove *gcc*, *g++*, *build-essential* and install *build-essential*.
To do the same, run this.

```
sudo apt remove gcc g++ build-essential && sudo apt update && sudo apt install build-essential
```

Hopefully it solves your problem.

Comment: installing `build-essential` solved the problem for me. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message:

> make: g++: Command not found

It isn't complaining that your version of Node is too old. It is complaining that it can't find a C++ compiler. You need to install g++ so it can compile the C++ components of the module.

Comment: can you share how I should install it ?

Comment: when trying to "sudo apt-get install g++" i'm getting this error:
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/mirror.isoc.org.il_pub_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Problem opening /var/lib/apt/lists/mirror.isoc.org.il_pub_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: I've used the following commands and problem not fixed! I'm getting the same error:
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*,
sudo apt-get update,
sudo apt-get install g++,
sudo npm install -g node-gyp,
sudo apt-get install build-essential,
sudo npm install libxml-xsd --save

Comment: g++ has the newest version:
INPUT:
sudo apt-get install g++

OUTPUT:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 183 not upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

RedHat users needs to have g++ compilers. Use the following command to install.

**dnf install gcc-c++**